# Shutdown command line and Message problems

Tags: batch-file

```
    set /p RESTART= WOULD YOU LIKE TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER NOW?(Y/N):
    echo.    

if %RESTART%==Y  (
              echo.
              echo.
              echo YOUR COMPUTER WILL BE REBOOTED IN 30 SECONDS!!!
              shutdown.exe /r /t 30
              goto Ryes
              ) else (
                  echo.
                  echo.
                  echo YOU CHOSE NOT TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER.
                  echo.
                  echo *****REMEMBER THAT YOU STILL NEED TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER SO THE CHANGES CAN BE APPLIED! *****
                    )

    :Ryes
    echo.
    set /p ABORT= WOULD YOU LIKE TO ABORT THE REBOOT?(Y/N):
    echo.

    :A
    shutdown /a

    pause
```

the Message "YOU CHOSE NOT TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER" still appears if I type Y.

Shutdown command doesn't work, I'm running the .bat as an Administrator.
Tried both for Windows XP and latest Windows Versions.

I'm typing y not Y. but I don't think this is the problem because the other user input chooses works just fine upper or lower case.
both shutdown commands:

```
shutdown -r -f -t 30
shutdown.exe /r /t 30
```

I know that because I get this message when trying to use the Abort option:

```
Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.(1116)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What is the problem with my Batch File?

Thank you for all your help and time.

Comment: You are typing `Y` and not `y`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more information about **[IF](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

You should modify this line :
`if %RESTART%==Y` to this line 
`If /I "%RESTART%"=="Y"`

> /I          Do a case Insensitive string comparison.

```
@echo off
set /p RESTART= WOULD YOU LIKE TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER NOW?(Y/N):
echo.    
If /I "%RESTART%"=="Y"  (
    echo.
    echo.
    echo YOUR COMPUTER WILL BE REBOOTED IN 30 SECONDS!!!
    shutdown.exe /r /t 30
    goto Ryes
    ) else (
    echo.
    echo.
    echo YOU CHOSE NOT TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER.
    echo.
    echo *****REMEMBER THAT YOU STILL NEED TO RESTART YOUR COMPUTER SO THE CHANGES CAN BE APPLIED! *****
)
pause
```

Comment: @Fred22 Changing `==` to `equ`is not necessary.  It is a bad programming practice for `IF` operands to be unquoted strings especially when value is from user input.  You need to code it as: `if /I "%RESTART%"=="Y" `

Answer (score 0):

add this before you check if the RESRART variable is defined as Y

```
if %RESTART%==y set restart=Y
```

Comment: That's rather unnecessary; `if` has an option for making a case-insensitive comparison.